# Remote Terminal Services speed up initial connection

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a windows 2003 64 bit remote terminal server with 30 clients connecting to it.

I noticed that when the client connects to the terminal server it takes 22 seconds to appear the following message "applying your personal settings", and then it takes 2 minutes to provide the user the final desktop.

Is there a way to figure out what happens when Personal settings are applyied and speed up the logon procedure?

Should I just increase the resources on the server?

Answer (score 0):

when personal settings are applied the group policies are applied. check the event viewer for errors.